# Fabricjs Effect Image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a picture that I'm carrying on a canvas by fabricjs

However need to do the effect indicated in the image below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChdwD.png]

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't tried anything so I will give you just a start and some hints so you can do it by yourself.

I made you a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjbznb3v/). If you press the Do effect it will set the right part from your effect. You have to do the bottom part. You also need to set the `top`, `left` and the `ctx` function based on your image `width` and `height`. And the final step would be to set that if the image moves also the 2 clones should move with it.

I hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Hello Nistor

I do not know much of the property transformMatrix / clipTo
I used your script as a base, could reverse and position the right place, however I can not "Leave off", no matter what and I change the width does not change.
http://jsfiddle.net/wjbznb3v/12/
Could you help me in this?

Comment: Here is your updated jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/wjbznb3v/13/ . Here is an example about clipping http://fabricjs.com/clipping/, here is an example with transformMatrix http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/. You still have to do some work to make it ok.